# Show floating button only for email verified users

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, floating-action-button

This floating button showing for all users but I need to show this floating button only for email verified users. I already done coding for email verification and it's working properly. I tried visibility on this floating button but its not working. I can't fix the error.

**My code:**

```
class FeedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FeedPage({Key key, this.scaffoldKey, this.refreshIndicatorKey})
      : super(key: key);

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;

  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> refreshIndicatorKey;

  Widget _floatingActionButton(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/CreateFeedPage/post');
      },
      child: customIcon(
        context,
        icon: AppIcon.plus,
        istwitterIcon: true,
        iconColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
        size: 25,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: _floatingActionButton(context),
      backgroundColor: TwitterColor.mystic,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: fullHeight(context),
          width: fullWidth(context),
          child: RefreshIndicator(
            key: refreshIndicatorKey,
            onRefresh: () async {
              /// refresh home page feed
              var feedState = Provider.of<FeedState>(context, listen: false);
              feedState.getDataFromDatabase();
              return Future.value(true);
            },
            child: _FeedPageBody(
              refreshIndicatorKey: refreshIndicatorKey,
              scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
 floatingActionButton: _floating(context, FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.emailVerified),
```

The widget

```
  Widget _floating(BuildContext context,bool isVerified){
    if (isVerified)
    return FloatingActionButton(
      //TODO: customise according to your needs
      onPressed:() async{
      },
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    );
    else
      return Container();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
floatingActionButton: Offstage(
offstage: _isVerified? false : true, 
child: _floatingActionButton(context),
),
```